# magento redirect to custom url after login

Tags: customer, login

i there any way i can add reffer like, so user can be redirected to that url after login, something like below

http://example.com/customer/account/login?u=product-page-url

i have already set below from admin

[image]

Comment: So you want to redirect specific product URL OR current Product URL after login?

Answer (score 0):

Note: In admin Customer redirect option should be set to "No":As you've already done it as per above image.

Create a new module or in existing module:
/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
<plugin name="vendor_module_loginpostplugin" type="\Vendor\Module\Plugin\LoginPostPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
</config>
```

/Vendor/Module/Plugin/LoginPostPlugin.php

```
<?php

/**
*
*/
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

/**
*
*/
class LoginPostPlugin
{

/**
 * Change redirect after login to home instead of dashboard.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $result
 */
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,
        $result)
    {
        $result->setPath('/'); // Change Here to where you want to redirect
        return $result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your case plugin is a better solution And i have tested and showing below code your helpful

I have create the simple module

**Custom/Redirect/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
    <plugin name="Custom_Redirect_loginpostplugin" type="Custom\Redirect\Plugin\LoginPostPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
  </type>
</config>
```

**Custom/Redirect/Plugin/LoginPostPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Redirect\Plugin;

class LoginPostPlugin
{

    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,
        $result)
    {
        $result->setPath('YourURL/'); // Change this to what you want
        return $result;
    }

}
```

**Custom/Redirect/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Custom_Redirect',
    __DIR__
);
```

Thanks.